# variable references an object's value, but is not updated when the object is

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm testing out Angular.js (quite enjoying it), but this might be more of a pure js question in fact.

The exercise scenario is that I have two matches:

- Player A vs. Player B
- The winner of the first match (Player A or B) vs. Player C

Here I am representing the first match:

```
$scope.match1 = {
   p1: "Player A",
   p2: "Player B",
   winner: "to be determined"
};
```

When I set up the second match, I declare a **variable with a reference** to the match 1 winner, as such:

```
$scope.match2 = {
   p1: $scope.match1.winner,
   p2: "Player C",
   winner: "tbd"
};
```

Now I have a button click which assigns a winner to match 1, but THIS VALUE IS NOT PASSED to match 2 (match2.p1 value remains "to be determined" although it references match1.winner which is now updated).

What gives? Thanks in advance for any help or contribution!

Here is a fiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/legolandbridge/mAjX5/2/

Comment: It's not a reference. You cannot refer to strings, they always get copied. The moment you do `p1: $scope.match1.winner` the value of that winner string is copied to `p1`. You can only refer to an object or a list.

Answer (score 6):

That is because your `winner` field is a string not an `object`. And you cannot get a reference to String. That will be value.

Have `winner` field as an `object` so when you will change your `winner`'s value it will be changed in `match2` also.

Try something like bellow.

```
function AppCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.match1 = { // p1 vs p2 
       p1: "Player A",
       p2: "Player B",
        winner: {name:"to be determined"} //Object
    };
    $scope.match2 = {
       p1: $scope.match1.winner, // an reference to winner of match one
       p2: "Player C",
       winner: "to be determined"
    };

    $scope.getWinner = function() { //on click
        $scope.match1.winner.name = "Player B"; 
        console.log($scope.match2.p1); //value is updated
    };


}
```

Comment: Thank you. It should have been obvious... but good to work through the code and specific problem nonetheless.